# How to count number of shares by specific user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I would like to run a contest among the users of my Facebook app and provide a prize to the users who share it the most time.

How do I get the number of shares performed PER user to my FB app? I will probably do it via PHP, but I'm pretty flexible with other platforms.

I know that I can use something like: http://graph.facebook.com/?id=YOUR_URL, but I want the number of shares per user and not the total shares of my app.

Thanks

Comment: I think something like this would not be in accordance with Facebook's [Platform Policy](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/) which state **IV. Application Integration Points**
_1.You must not incentivize users to use (or gate content behind the use of) Facebook social channels, or imply that an incentive is directly tied to the use of our channels._